# how to connect my css files in a cakephp website?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I want to use my css file.

I used

```
$this->Html->css(array('style'), array('charset'=>'utf-8', 'inline' => false));
```

But this code keeps pointing 'myPageFolder/css/style.css'. 
Not 'myPageFolder/app/webroot/css/style.css'

How can I make that code point /app/webroot/css/style.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
<?php
    echo $this->fetch('css');
    echo $this->Html->css('style');         
?>
```

root htaccess  yourapp/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]   
</IfModule>
```

htaccess found in  yourapp/app/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]   
</IfModule>
```

htaccess inside webroot  /app/webroot/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

please check also index.php found in the root directory yourapp/index.php

```
<?php
define('APP_DIR', 'app');
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
define('WEBROOT_DIR', 'webroot');
define('WWW_ROOT', ROOT . DS . APP_DIR . DS . WEBROOT_DIR . DS);

if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
    define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', ROOT . DS . 'lib');
}

require APP_DIR . DS . WEBROOT_DIR . DS . 'index.php';

?>
```

Comment: It didn't work.. Is there any chance that my index.php files are wrong ? I mean the files where I define the WWW_ROOT, APP_DIR or something?